# argument "destdir" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, terminal

In my Linux Mint 17 terminal, I start `R` simple by typing:

```
> R
```

Then, when I do `install.packages('foo')`, I get:

```
argument "destdir" is missing, with no default
```

How should I choose my `destdir`? And why is it not set by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On *my* system at least, uninstalling the `rbase` package resolved this problem (presumably because the system then 'fell back' to some default version):

```
apt remove r-base
```

Now I get the following:

```
bash > R
> install.packages('foo')
Installing package into ‘/home/rob/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
```

And the installation proceeds as expected.

Comment: Equally, in another situation where I was back to this same error, *installing* the `r-base` package got me going again. Odd...

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
.libPaths(new = "/home/someuser/R/library")
```

Although it is supposed to be set automatically when installing R as someone commented. So you might want to try reinstalling R altogether if you're suspicious other things might have gone wrong with the install.

Comment: That is unnecessary when R is properly set up.

Comment: @KonradRudolph more specifically...?

Comment: It’s simply unnecessary. When R is properly installed, it sets a default library path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on a windows machine and solved the problem by exiting RStudio and restarting as administrator. Then running `install.packages('foo')` works fine and the desired library files are added to the library location specified in `.libPaths()`. You can call this function in the R console to see the location.